# iOS 6 status bar tint and modal dialog

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I'm working on an application that displays coloured `UINavigationBar` images, with different colours for different screens.

The iOS 6 status bar tint matches these different colours as expected when switching between views in my `UITabBarController`. However, when I present a modal `UITabBarController`, it seems the `UINavigationBar` image is being ignored.

Is there any way to fix this?

Correct status bar tints:

[image: Correct tint]
[image: Correct tint]

`UITabBarController` with blue `UINavigationController` images is now presented, tint is incorrect:

[image: Incorrect tint]